# Gallery with different image sizes

Tags: android, gallery, imageview, aspect-ratio

I have a gallery with different image sizes the custom layout is below for Gallery, its working correctly if the image width is les than height but if image height is less than width its not working correctly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="5dip"
    android:paddingRight="5dip"
    android:focusable="true">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="80dip"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" 
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@+id/image"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="60dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But its not maintaining the aspect ratio, I am stuck to it why its not working as desired

**Update:**

[image]

Comment: yup the problem is with my code of scaling images what I was doing creating thumbs of 90x120 no matter the image is in portrait or in landscape mode

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Maybe post that as the answer to this question and mark it as such.  Just so others can have an answer when viewing your post.